# `Rails 7 --api` session cookie set - but not sent back subsequently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flutter, session-cookies

I have a `rails --api` back-end running on `localhost:3000` and a Flutter web-app running on `localhost:8080`.

As per documentation, I have configured session middleware and CORS in Rails as follows:

```
(config/application.rb)

config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_interslice_session', domain: 'localhost:3000'
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.use config.session_store, config.session_options

(config/initializers/cors.rb)

Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'http://localhost:8080'
    resource '*',
    headers: :any,
    credentials: true,
    methods: [:get, :post, :options, :put, :path]
  end
end
```

Now, here is the issue. I'm able to authenticate a user. And I even get a `Set-cookie` in the response header back (as shown below)

[image: Set-cookie on sign-in]

But I do not seem to get this `Cookie` back in subsequent requests

[image]

1. So, how do I get the browser (Chrome / Firefox) to save this cookie so that it is sent back with every subsequent request?
2. Are there any HTTP headers I need to set when issuing a request from Flutter?
3. Or, is there something amiss with my Rails configuration?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I forgot to mention. I'm using the devise gem for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't figure out how to get the browser to save a cross-site cookies for the next request - even though I tried many things, including deploying SSL certificates locally (using `mkcert`)

But then it turned out, I didn't need to. If I implemented the same setup as I have in production, namely, `nginx` web-server serving `puma` and `flutter` using socket files, then it turns out all requests are considers `SAMEORIGIN`.

As a result, `CORS` does not even come into the picture. And hence, neither do issues related to cross-site cookies.

On the downside, I can't hot-reload my flutter web-app while developing. Have to re-build manually and reload the browser.